# Wordpress move from MAMP to hosting

Tags: wordpress, hosting, live, mamp

I've done these things:

1. Export import base
2. Update wp-config
3. Zip and send to hosting via FTP
4. Unzip and run
5. Test admin and posts. Ok!
6. Try go to www.itpodcasts.com.ua get redirected to www.itpodcasts.com.ua:8888 that couldn't be resolved.

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Somebody know how fix it?

Comment: Is there a plugin that is redirecting the site, perhaps? Or maybe something in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question. Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), server logs, a _real_ domain name or a detailed report of exactly what is being redirected to where-- step by step--, the contents of your `.htaccess` file. And any other information you have to offer.

Comment: Done. Debug log, don't add any info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to run those queries into your database

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');
```

Comment: Along with this, there are various other things you can check. One tool I use a lot is "Search & Replace Tool" which takes care of serialized data too. I would recommend duplicating the staging db before using this tool in case something borks.

http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/